# How to get index of Image on mouse hover in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, image-gallery, flipkart-api

I'm trying to implement below points in my project.

1. I'm trying to implement same image box and functionality like the below link. [Demo Implemenation link](https://www.flipkart.com/realme-11-pro-5g-oasis-green-256-gb/p/itm5647cce338e55?pid=MOBGPU8HCGG9PCER&lid=LSTMOBGPU8HCGG9PCERHGOPBG&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=realme%2011%20pro%205g&store=tyy%2F4io&srno=s_1_1&otracker=AS_Query_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_10_na_na_ps&otracker1=AS_Query_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_10_na_na_ps&fm=organic&iid=755db92d-f3ac-446b-9faf-792d53ce24de.MOBGPU8HCGG9PCER.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=uhp4iq9ni80000001695794812507&qH=112d94a1f980828e)
2. In my code I've already implemented the side box feature, but just wanted to know how to get index of image with all the details when I hover over that image.
3. I wanted to show the image same as above link while hovering over.

Please help me out. Below is my code.

```js
  @ViewChild('hello',{static:false}) FirstRef!:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('next',{static:false}) Next!:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('prev',{static:false}) Prev!:ElementRef;

  SideImagesIcons=['../../../../assets/Product/p1.webp','../../../../assets/Product/p2.webp','../../../../assets/Product/p3.webp',
  '../../../../assets/Product/p4.webp','../../../../assets/Product/p5.webp','../../../../assets/Product/p6.webp','../../../../assets/Product/p7.webp'
,'../../../../assets/Product/p8.webp']

SideImages=['../../../assets/Product/p1.webp','../../../assets/Product/p2.webp','../../../assets/Product/p3.webp','../../../assets/Product/p4.webp'
,'../../../assets/Product/p5.webp','../../../assets/Product/p6.webp','../../../assets/Product/p7.webp','../../../assets/Product/p8.webp','../../../assets/Product/p9.webp']


imageArrayToDisplay:string[]=[];
displaySize=5;
displayIndex=0;
startIndex=0;
selectedIndex=0;
prevIndex=this.displaySize;
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.imageArrayToDisplay=this.SideImagesIcons.slice(this.startIndex,this.currentIndex);
   console.log("current index = "+this.currentIndex+"\nDisplay Index "+this.displayIndex+"\nStart Index"+this.startIndex+"\nPrev Index"+this.prevIndex);
  }

  prevClick(){
    this.prevIndex=this.startIndex-1;
    if(this.displayIndex>this.displaySize && this.prevIndex>=0)
    {
      this.displayIndex--;
      this.imageArrayToDisplay=this.SideImagesIcons.slice(this.prevIndex,this.displayIndex)
     this.startIndex--;
     this.Next.nativeElement.style.display='block';
    }
   this.currentIndex=this.displayIndex;
   if(this.prevIndex<=0)
   {
    this.Prev.nativeElement.style.display='none';
   }
   console.log("current index = "+this.currentIndex+"\nDisplay Index "+this.displayIndex+"\nStart Index"+this.startIndex+"\nPrev Index"+this.prevIndex);
    
    
  }
  currentIndex=this.displaySize;
  nextClick(){
    this.displayIndex=this.currentIndex+1;
    this.startIndex+=1;
    //this loop will run till to show the images till it reaches the last image
    if(this.displayIndex>this.displaySize && this.displayIndex <=this.SideImagesIcons.length)
    {
      this.imageArrayToDisplay=this.SideImagesIcons.slice(this.startIndex,this.displayIndex)
      this.currentIndex++;
      this.Prev.nativeElement.style.display='block';
    }
    //this will handle if we reaches to last image
    else if(this.currentIndex<=this.SideImagesIcons.length)
    {
      this.currentIndex=this.SideImagesIcons.length;
      this.displayIndex=this.currentIndex;
      this.startIndex=(this.SideImagesIcons.length-this.displaySize);
      this.Next.nativeElement.style.display='none';
    }
    console.log("current index = "+this.currentIndex+"\nDisplay Index "+this.displayIndex+"\nStart Index"+this.startIndex);
  }
```

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center; */
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    align-content: center;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
}

.side {
    width: 108px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.side::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.slide-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.slide-box ul {
    transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .4s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    list-style: none;
}

.slide-box ul li {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.inside {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.inside-li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.inside-li img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.btn-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 39%;
    width: 64%;
    display: none;
}

.btn-next {
    width: 64%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32%;
    left: 37%;
}

.enlarge-box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.inside-img-box {
    padding: 5px;
}

.inside-img-box .inside-li img {
    max-height: 99%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="side">
                        <div class="slide-box">
                            <ul>
                                <li *ngFor="let prod of imageArrayToDisplay; let i=index">
                                    <div class="inside">
                                        <div class="inside-li">
                                            <img [src]="prod" alt="" [ngClass]="{'active':selectedIndex ===i}"> {{i}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button #prev class="btn-primary btn-prev" (click)="prevClick()">Prev</button>
                            <button #next class="btn-success btn-next" (click)="nextClick()">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="enlarge-box">
                        <div class="image-box">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="inside-img-box">
                                        <div class="inside-li">
                                            <img src="../../../assets/Product/p1.webp" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <p #hello>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `(hover)` event and expose the current iteration image to a variable

for example:

```
<li *ngFor="let prod of imageArrayToDisplay; let i=index">
    <div class="inside">
       <div class="inside-li">
           <img (hover)="imageHover(prod)" [src]="prod" alt="" [ngClass]="{'active':selectedIndex ===i}"> {{i}}
       </div>
    </div>                                    
</li>
```

and on the `imageHover` method save the `prod` argument to a class variable
(name it for the example - `currentImageUrl`)and read it from the template on the place you want to display the big image

```
<div class="inside-img-box">
    <div class="inside-li">
           <img [src]="currentImageUrl" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```